# Is it possible to use matchTemplate from openCV to track a template region in a movie?

Tags: python, opencv, matchtemplate

I have a .tif file (greyscale, 8-bit), which is essentially a sequence of images over time. I have an object that is moving over time, so has a different position in each frame, and I'd like to use matchTemplate to "follow" this object over the course of my movie. Is this possible and, if so, how would I go about it?

I have applied matchTemplate to a few individual frames of my movie, and it worked really well on some of them (first and last and some in between), I just can't seem to figure out how to go through all my timepoints to get tracking of this element

Extra question, is it possible to update the template at each frame? More specifically, can I detect the object on the first frame, and then use the detected region as a template for detection on the next frame? The reason for this is that the object changes shape slightly over time, especially in the middle frames, so I couldn't detect the object using my original template on some of the intermediate frames (it goes back to the original shape in the final frames, though).

Thank you, I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.